# Materialize 1.0.0-beta (CSS Transitions)

Tags: html, css, front-end, materialize, transição

Sou novo em front end em geral, tenho conhecimento básico de html e css, gostaria de usar o materialize e entender esta função aqui.
http://materializecss.com/css-transitions.html

pois eu tento usar estes códigos presente na página só que não consigo usar o "Toggle Scale" em minha página

```
  <!-- Scaled in -->
  <a id="scale-demo" href="#!" class="btn-floating btn-large scale-transition">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
  </a>

  <!-- Scaled out -->
  <a id="scale-demo" href="#!" class="btn-floating btn-large scale-transition scale-out">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
  </a>
```

já inspecionei a própria página para ver como eles fizeram mas na prática eu nunca consigo usar essa função de clicar e esconder um objeto, copiei os códigos para a minha mas mesmo assim não da certo (os arquivos do materialize estão organizados e copiei o html que eles recomendam)

```
<a id="scale-demo-trigger" href="#!" class="btn right">Toggle Scale</a>
```

até mesmo usei este código fonte acima presente na página para ativar o "Toggle Scale" mas mesmo assim não dá certo, gostaria de um exemplo funcional se possível para mim entender na prática, desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Setou os scripts da biblioteca?

Comment: Pelo que vi. Você não setou a biblioteca. Neste link está explicando. Pegue a opção por cdn por ser a mais rápida. http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

Comment: Sim, setei tudo corretamente como está no site, pois os outros componentes estão funcionando, eu não sabia que no caso este "css transition" do materialize tinha que definir o uso via javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

na verdade você precisa criar um código que altere as classes, fiz um exemplo em que o clique faz desaparecer e volta 1 segundo depois:

```js
var scale = document.getElementById('scale-demo')

var b = true

scale.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (b) {
    scale.className = 'btn-floating btn-large scale-transition scale-out'
    setTimeout(function() {
      scale.className = 'btn-floating btn-large scale-transition scale-in'
    }, 1000)
  } else {
    scale.className = 'btn-floating btn-large scale-transition scale-in'
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />

<a id="scale-demo" href="#!" class="btn-floating btn-large scale-transition">
  <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</a>
```

O Materialize tem essas classes mas são só o efeito de "diminuir" e "aumentar", eles não acontecem por conta própria, você deve definir o uso

Answer (score 0):

Achei uma solução interessante que fica igual ao modelo de referência do site

```js
function toggleButton() {
  var scale = document.getElementById('scale-demo');
  scale.classList.toggle('scale-out');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<a id="scale-demo" href="#!" class="btn-floating btn-large scale-transition">
  <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</a>
<a id="scale-trigger" href="#!" onclick="toggleButton()" class="btn-large">
            Toggle
        </a>
```